# Collect numbers from a texboxes, sort them, and put them back numerically?

Tags: javascript, html, sorting, debugging

Here's my code. I randomly input numbers into the textboxes.

```
<html>
<body>

<p>
    txt1: <input type = "text" id = "number1" value = ""><br>
    txt2: <input type = "text" id = "number2" value = ""><br>
    txt3: <input type = "text" id = "number3" value = ""><br>
    txt4: <input type = "text" id = "number4" value = ""><br>
    txt5: <input type = "text" id = "number5" value = ""><br>
</p>

<script>
    function randomNumbers() {
        var a = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1);
        var b = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1);
        var c = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1);
        var d = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1);
        var e = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1);
        document.getElementById("number1").value = a;
        document.getElementById("number2").value = b;
        document.getElementById("number3").value = c;
        document.getElementById("number4").value = d;
        document.getElementById("number5").value = e;
    }

</script>

<button 
    onclick = "randomNumbers()">rand_button
</button>

<script>
    function sort(a,b){
        return(a-b)
    }
    function sortNumbers(){
        var v = document.getElementById("number1").value;
        var w = document.getElementById("number2").value;
        var x = document.getElementById("number3").value;
        var y = document.getElementById("number4").value;
        var z = document.getElementById("number5").value;
        var numbersArray = new array["v", "w", "x", "y", "z"];
        numbersArray.sort(sort);
        document.getElementById("number1").value = sorted_string_of_values;
        document.getElementById("number2").value = sorted_string_of_values;
        document.getElementById("number3").value = sorted_string_of_values;
        document.getElementById("number4").value = sorted_string_of_values;
        document.getElementById("number5").value = sorted_string_of_values;
    }
</script>

<button
    onclick = "sortNumbers()">sort_button
</button>

</body>
</html>
```

It seems like I failed to collect the numbers from the textboxes. So how can I put the inputs into am array before I sort it?

Comment: Try remove double quotes from array, var numbersArray = new array["v", "w", "x", "y", "z"];. It should be: var numbersArray = new array[v, w, x, y, z];

Comment: @MuhammadIdrees tried...but still cant sort

Comment: Debug the array, if array contains all your values. then we move to next thing: the SORT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `sortNumbers()`

```
 var numbersArray = new Array(v, w, x, y, z); // NOTICE! No box brackets and Array with Capital A
 numbersArray.sort(sort);
 document.getElementById("number1").value = numbersArray[0];
 document.getElementById("number2").value = numbersArray[1];
 document.getElementById("number3").value = numbersArray[2];
 document.getElementById("number4").value = numbersArray[3];
 document.getElementById("number5").value = numbersArray[4];
```

EDIT:

In your original code, there was a syntax error.
When you do `var numbersArray = new array[];` there are two errors.

First, in your code, there is no such thing as `array`. I assume that what you want to do is `new Array` (Array with capital `A`)

And if you're going to use `new Array` syntax, then using `new Array[]` is wrong. It will say `Uncaught TypeError: Array` is not a funtion.

So what you need to do is,

`var numbersArray = new array(v, w, x, y, z);` and since you want to use values of v,w,x,y and z, there should be no quotes with them.

[Check this Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AdityaParab/dd83nfqp/)

Comment: still cant...when i clicked the sort button nothing happen

Comment: is there any error? I have attached fiddle. Please check updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can simplify your code.

Instead of selecting inputs individually via `id`, you can query using a selector [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll). This will return collection of elements (nodeList), on which you can then call array methods.

Here is an example, with explanation in code comments:

```js
// select all inputs inside the p with id container
var inputs = document.querySelectorAll('#container > input');

// listen for click event on button with id btn
document.getElementById('btn1').addEventListener("click", randomNumbers);
document.getElementById('btn2').addEventListener("click", sortNumbers);


function randomNumbers() {
    var arr = [], len = inputs.length;
    // create an array with random numbers
    for (var i=0; i < len; i++) {
        arr.push(Math.floor(Math.random() * len))
    } 
    // iterate the colletion assign the new array values
    [].forEach.call(inputs, function(elem, i) {
        elem.value = arr[i];
    })  
}

function sortNumbers() {
    
    // iterate the collection and get values into a new array and sort it
    var arr = [].map.call(inputs, function(elem) {
        return elem.value;
    }).sort();
  
    // iterate the colletion again and assign the new array values back
    [].forEach.call(inputs, function(elem, i) {
        elem.value = arr[i];
    })
}
```

```html
<p id="container">
    txt1: <input type="text" id="number1" value="4"><br>
    txt2: <input type="text" id="number2" value="8"><br>
    txt3: <input type="text" id="number3" value="1"><br>
    txt4: <input type="text" id="number4" value="3"><br>
    txt5: <input type="text" id="number5" value="2"><br>
</p>
<button id="btn1">Randomize</button>
<button id="btn2">Sort</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this to create & sort array:

```
var numbersArray = [v, w, x, y, z];
numbersArray.sort(function(a, b){return a-b});
```

Edit:
then assign indexed item for each textbox, like: numbersArray[0]